# Replacement for NoNameScript that works with latest version of mIRC?

Tags: windows, irc, mirc

I was using **NoNameScript** for a while, but it doesn't work with latest mIRC versions and is no longer being developed.

Is there are way to get NoNameScript to work with the latest version or a similar replacement?

Comment: Subjective "list of" and "what's your favourite" type questions are [off topic](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask) on Super User, I'd highly recommend you change your question to just ask for a replacement for the specific script you have, otherwise this will be closed shortly.

Comment: I've just taken the liberty of adjusting the question for you as it was gaining close votes and flags, hopefully now it should be a better fit and you might be able to get some solid answers.

Comment: Since ESNation (the creators of NNScript) has apparently shut down, I'm surprised this question doesn't have any answers.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I've found so far is http://www.ircap.net/ (Note: Spanish website)

It apparently works with the latest version of mIRC, and has a lot of features, but it seems a bit more "in your face" than NNScript. Apparently "picture windows" are all the rage these days.